# Problem: Main confirmation window is shown behind in the dimmed area in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid

When the grid is opened, the background is dimmed. When I choose to delete some rows, a confirmation to delete is shown and but it appears in the dimmed background: i.e. the grid is still in the front while the delete confirmation is what supposed to be in the front. What could be the reason behind that?

```
$("#termsGrid").jqGrid('navGrid','#termsGridPager',
    {edit:false,add:false,del:true,search:true,view:true,refresh:true}, 
    // edit options 
    {},
    // add options
    {},
    //del options
    {
        msg: "Selected records(s) will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered.<br/> Are you sure?",
        afterSubmit : gridAfterSubmit,
        reloadAfterSubmit: true,
        closeOnEscape:true
    },
    // search options
    {multipleSearch:true,closeOnEscape:true},
    //view options
    {
        closeOnEscape:true
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a CSS-problem.

Try adjusting your stylesheet with the appropriate z-index-value for your confirmation message. Those are probably positioned absolute and if you don't define the correct order (with z-index) this can lead to your problem.

If you are having problem in finding the correct classes/ids or style-values, use [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/firebug/) with [Firefox](http://www.mozilla-europe.org/de/firefox/).

Comment: I can't find the place where I could change it, is it possible to set somewhere within in this code?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change (increase) the "z-index" CSS attribute of the Delete dialog. To do this by defining of additional Del options

```
beforeShowForm: function(form) {
    form.closest(".ui-jqdialog").css({"z-index":"3000"});
}
```

Here the value 3000 can be set to any other value. The default value used by jqGrid is 950.